# Can a Windows update be "canceled" after it is "installed" but before it is "updated"?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

After clicking the "Check for updates" button from the Windows Update settings dialog, a ".NET Update Preview" immediately began to download and install (I forgot that the "*check*" button sometimes *installs* things, including beta previews).

A reboot is now required to "update". So, has the "update" yet been "installed"?

If it has been installed, is there a way to prevent the "update" from happening before a reboot, so that it can be "remove"/"uninstalled"?

If the "update" has not yet been "installed", is it possible to prevent the pending "update" from installing/"updating" before a reboot.

I do not want an update preview, but rather to simply ensure that all updates were finished before installing OEM drivers, to minimize interference.

Comment: You can probably find the article number in the windows updates, it should allow you to uninstall it, regardless if a reboot is required for it to be "fully" installed.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala The KB number, in update history? Probably, but I also do not want a corrupted system.

Comment: Search the c drive for "pending.xml" delete it, and the update will not be installed.

Answer (score 2):

> A reboot is now required to "update". So, has the "updated" yet been
> "installed"?

The update has been installed and the restart is required to complete the install. There is no native way of backing out of that.

> If it has been installed, is there a way to prevent the "update" from
> happening before a reboot, so that I can "remove"/"uninstall" the
> pending "update"?

Pretty much the same answer as above. In fact, numerous other updates will not even occur until the restart has taken place. Windows tries to ensure later (in time) updates do not occur before earlier (in time) updates.

> I do not want an update preview, but rather to simply ensure that all
> updates were finished before installing OEM drivers, to minimize
> interference.

You need to at least complete this sequence now before installing drivers. That is, do driver updates after.

If completely necessary, you can sometimes roll back an update and that may help.

If you have a working restore point, you may be able to roll back to a prior point. This is not always possible.

Comment: Can I simply remove the update preview after a reboot, when it completes install, or does this have any risks ("2021-10 Cumulative Update Preview for .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8 for Windows 10 Version 21H1 for x64 (KB5006365)")? Maybe I'll do another backup first.

Comment: You can check the update documentation to see if the update can be uninstalled. It varies by the actual update.

Comment: Why are you worried about an .NET backup exactly?